# jQuery validation of controls

Tags: javascript, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery

I am looking at validation of some text boxes for things like required, 
minlength, max length, email etc... I am able to get examples that work fine on submit button on page. I want to do this validation on a button click which will only raise a Ajax request and not submit of page.

On the Internet all the samples found was with a submit button. Is there an 
easy way to change this code a little bit to make it work for non submit button click or any 
new jQuery or Java plugin to do the same?

I am using the `jquery.validation.js` for now. This works with submit buttons.

Any kind of help with suggestion or help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't use a button, use a submit, then handle the ajax in the onsubmit event (and stop event propagation so the normal submission doesn't happen if the JS runs). This way you avoid violating rule two: http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery validator plugin already handles this. Just tweak some of the options in the `validate` method.

As quoted in the documentation for the *onfocusout* option:

> Validate elements (except checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur. If nothing is entered, all rules are skipped, except when the field was already marked as invalid.

Code Example:

```
$("#form").validate({
  onfocusout: false
});
```

That's just one of a few dozen options you can configure. You can see the full list of options for the `validate` method here:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options